# Node js, Sails js, SAP ASE database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sybase, sap-ase

How can I connect to the SAP ASE database with NodeJs' sails freemwork.
for example, I have provided the MySQL connection with MySQL workbench, what do you recommend for connecting with SAP ASE.

Comment: Which SAP Database? HANA, Sybase?

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem

Comment: / Node_modules / Sybase / dist
add jconnect16.jar file to the file path. Then add "this.props.put (" ENCRYPT_PASSWORD "," true ") to the SybaseDB.java file from the / src folder;
then paste the try block "Class.forName (" com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver "). newInstance ();
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc: sybase: Tds:" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname, props);
     return true; "
  Paste.

Comment: note: the specified actions are valid for nodejs.